# Rhandsontable kept flashing upon restoring from bookmark

Tags: r, shiny, bookmarks, rhandsontable

My app has a small table that users can update their own values. I want users to be able to restore their work via bookmarking. However, I dont know why the numbers in the table kept flashing and switching between the original values and the edited values when the bookmark url is restored. Could someone shed some light into the issue? Here is an example of what was happening after the users changed the value from 258 to 2 and then calling the bookmark url.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(rhandsontable)
library(tidyverse)

dataResultsUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  rHandsontableOutput(ns("result"))
}

dataResults <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input,output,session) {
      data <- reactive(mtcars %>% slice(1:5))
      
      tmp <- reactiveVal()
      observeEvent(data(),{tmp(data())})
      
      output$result <- renderRHandsontable({
        rhandsontable(tmp(),rowHeaders = NULL,height = 500)
      })
      
      #Bookmark user inputs for result table
      onBookmark(function(state) {
        state$values$editedtbl <- tmp()
      })
      
      onRestored(function(state) {
        print(state$values$editedtbl)
        if(!is.null(state$values$editedtbl)) {
          tmp(state$values$editedtbl)
        }
      })
      
      observeEvent(input$result,{
        df <- hot_to_r(input$result)
        df <- as.data.frame(df)
        tmp(df)
      })
    }
  )
} 

# Main app code
ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(
    dataResultsUI("data"),
    bookmarkButton()
  )
}
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dataResults("data")
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "server")
```